# Android contacts, how to build a chained query

Tags: android, rawcontacts

I'd like to do the following:
Retrieve list of all contact (including photos), that have raw contact of some specific account.

The problem is that the photo thumbnail can be retrieved only with ***Contacts.CONTENT_URI***, and raw contact info, like account type, can be retrieved with ***ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI***, so i'm doubt it can be done by single query.

My idea is - first - to find all raw contacts of the specific account, and then retrieve the contacts that has ***RawContacts.CONTACT_IDs*** of the previous results. I hope i'm clear enough.

How can i perform two queries, where the second one uses the results of the first ?

Comment: I think you can do it in a single query like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866165/how-to-get-android-contact-thumbnail)

Comment: If i understand correctly, it means that after retrieving the Cursor with raw contacts of my account, i should loop over the data and perform a photo query for each id ?